# Validating parts of a date/time that is entered as separate fields

Tags: asp.net, validation

Environment: ASP.NET 3.5, Visual Studio 2008

I have 3 textboxes

```
TextBox1.Text = "is a date value";
TextBox2.Text = "is hour of a datetime";
TextBox3.Text = "is minutes of a datetime";
```

(don't ask why :) it's one of those...it just is )

Is there a way to use a single asp.net validator control to check (**client and server-side**) if the combination of all 3 textboxes is a valid datetime?

Also, seems to me can have various possibilities (i.e. just enters something in one of the textboxes, valid date but invalid time, etc.)

If it's not possible what would the server-side check look like?

For example, this is what I have so far:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    DateTime dateOutput = default(DateTime);
    DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out dateOutput);

    if (dateOutput != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        string dateString = string.Empty;

        if (TextBox2.Text == string.Empty && TextBox3.Text == string.Empty)
            dateString = dateString = string.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", TextBox1.Text, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute);
        DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateOutput);
    }
    args.IsValid = (dateOutput != DateTime.MinValue);
}
```

Am I missing anything or can it be improved?

Answer (score 0):

User input *must* be validated via client script and server script. You may select `customValidator`. You may also validate input by handling `onsubmit` event of `<form/>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateMyForm(){
    //write code to validate user input.
    if(!succeed)
       return false;
    return true; 
  }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return validateMyForm()">
      ...
</form>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear but I'm more interested in the best way to validate the date case (specifically the server-side routine).